# How to append a list of dictionaries to the value of a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, ordereddictionary, dictionary-comprehension

For example:

```
list1 = [{'vehicle': {'bmw': 2, 'cus': 'mr x', 'extra': 'he is awesome'}}, 
        {'fruit': {'mango': 2, 'color': 'gelb', 'extra': 'king of fruits'}}]

print(list1)
```

> [{'vehicle': {'bmw': 2, 'cus': 'mr x', 'extra': 'he is awesome'}},
>   {'fruit': {'mango': 2, 'color': 'gelb', 'extra': 'king of fruits'}}]

```
final_ds_dict={}

final_ds_dict.update({'datasets': {'training': list1}})

print(final_ds_dict)
```

The output I am getting is as follows:

```
{'datasets': {'training': [{'vehicle': {'bmw': 2,
     'cus': 'mr x',
     'extra': 'he is awesome'}},
   {'fruit': {'mango': 2, 'color': 'gelb', 'extra': 'king of fruits'}}]}}
```

However, I don't to append it as list.

The Desired output should be as follows:

```
{'datasets': {'training': {'vehicle': {'bmw': 2,
     'cus': 'mr x',
     'extra': 'he is awesome'}},
   {'fruit': {'mango': 2, 'color': 'gelb', 'extra': 'king of fruits'}}}}
```

Can someone please help resolve this?

Comment: Your desired output isn't a valid python dict. Maybe you have an extra `{` before fruit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `dict` to form the inner dictionary:

```
list1 = [{'vehicle': {'bmw': 2, 'cus': 'mr x', 'extra': 'he is awesome'}}, 
    {'fruit': {'mango': 2, 'color': 'gelb', 'extra': 'king of fruits'}}]
result = {'datasets':dict(i for b in list1 for i in b.items())}
```

Output:

```
{'datasets': 
    {'vehicle': {'bmw': 2, 'cus': 'mr x', 'extra': 'he is awesome'}, 
     'fruit': {'mango': 2, 'color': 'gelb', 'extra': 'king of fruits'}
    }
}
```